# how to split a column that is created with array_agg

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to split up an arrayed column that was created using an array_agg.  the following is severely cut down, original query is something like 210 lines

```
select 
 distinct on (visitor.id)
 id,
 array_agg(distinct item.code::text)

from
 8xfullouter joins

where
exists(
select
distinct on(visitor.id)
item.code::text
from
3 full outer join that all appear in the first query

group by
visit.id, 
item.code

order by 
visit.id
)
```

I need to break the array_agg(distinct item.code::text)  into multiple columns.  I've tried split_part(array_agg(distinct item.code::text), ',', 1) but received the following

```
> [Err] ERROR:  function split_part(character varying[], unknown,
> integer) does not exist LINE 159: split_part (array_agg(distinct
> "public".procedure_group_cpt_...
```

thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an index of the array, e.g.:

```
select (array_agg(code::text))[1] 
from (values ('code1'), ('code2')) as codes(code)

 array_agg 
-----------
 code1
(1 row)
```

Alternatively, you can use `string_agg()` instead of `array_agg()`, e.g.:

```
select split_part(string_agg(code::text, ','), ',', 1)
from (values ('code1'), ('code2')) as codes(code)

 split_part 
------------
 code1
(1 row)
```